# Can't Modify MPRemoteCommandCenter Actions when using MPMusicPlayerController

Tags: ios, xcode, ipod, mpmusicplayercontroller

My app uses `MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()` to play audio which works well.

The user is able to set a custom `currentPlaybackRate`. This works as expected.

If the user presses an action on the lock screen (the `MPRemoteCommandCenter`), the `currentPlaybackRate` is reset to 1. This is because events are sent directly to the system music player, not the app controller.

To set the `currentPlaybackRate` to the proper value, I tried to override `MPRemoteCommandCenter` events:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "willEnterForeground:", name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "playbackStateChanged:", name: MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification, object: player)
    player.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()

    let rcc : MPRemoteCommandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.sharedCommandCenter()
    rcc.playCommand.addTargetWithHandler { (event: MPRemoteCommandEvent!) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
        NSLog("Lock Screen Play Pressed")
        return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus.Success
    }
    rcc.togglePlayPauseCommand.addTargetWithHandler { (event: MPRemoteCommandEvent!) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
        NSLog("Lock Screen Play/Pause Pressed")
        return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus.Success
    }
}
```

Is `MPRemoteCommandCenter` supposed to respect `addTargetWithHandler` when using `MPMusicPlayerController`?

Comment: Do you solve this problem?

Comment: I have another branch where I've completely replaced `MPMusicPlayerController` with `AVAudioPlayer`. It works, but means your controller needs to handle much more logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this solution if you don't really need MPMusicPlayerController
https://github.com/gangverk/GVMusicPlayerController
This guy combine behaviors of AVAudioPlayer and MPMusicPlayerController.

But I steel need for an answer. Because in my app I really need MPMusicPlayerController.