# How can we implement slider to forward songs from iphone lock screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Like default music app can we implement functionality to drag slider to forward backward song. This is useful if song is long and u want a quick view.

*This question is misread as playing audio while iphone is locked. but its actually one step further. how to add a draggable slider in lock screen, so that we can jump song to specific location. for example i want to listen song from 1 minutes onward, i can drag it. * See attached image, its highlighted in red. [image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle background audio playing while iOS device is locked or on another application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429204/how-to-handle-background-audio-playing-while-ios-device-is-locked-or-on-another)

Comment: thats not duplication. read question carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The [`MPRemoteCommandCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPRemoteCommandCenter_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPRemoteCommandCenter/changePlaybackRateCommand) class reference describes ways to respond to commands such as play/pause, and seeking, but does not appear to provide the ability to use a slider to seek within the track. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29168373/834998) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8518279/834998) for more details.

Comment: I have some developers app doing that. So its possible. Just need to dig it.   I know seeking notification and implemented that. But slider is more convenient.

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/listen-gesture-music-player/id768223310?mt=8 see this app as a example of implement this feature